# How to decode CSR file using Perl?

Tags: perl, openssl

I'm currently working on a project for which I need to decode a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) -- basically mimic a site something [like this](https://www.sslshopper.com/csr-decoder.html). So, by pasting the CSR in a text area, the value will be passed in the backend and then decode the information and display it in the page.

The problem is that I need to run this using Perl, and I'm having a hard time looking for a good resource to start. I had already looked into [`OpenCA::OpenSSL`](http://search.cpan.org/~madwolf/OpenCA-OpenSSL-0.9.91/OpenSSL.pod) but it seems like there's no available function that would fit when extracting the information in the details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried searching the CPAN? [`Crypt::PKCS10`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::PKCS10) should be a good start

Comment: Thank you for answering.

I'm trying to do some solution other than the Crypt::PKCS10 and is something like these:

1. Using perl, I'll be running a command using the openssl such as this --

$getResults = `openssl req -in test.csr -text -noout`;
print $getResults;

and then the $getResults will be parse and split and will be evaluated to get the Subject Information (Common Name, Org Unit, Organization, etc..) and it's Key Size. 

Do you think would this work? or is this a good approach?

Comment: Yes I believe that would work too. Just be sure to use backticks `\`openssl req -in test.csr -text -noout\`` or the `qx/openssl req -in test.csr -text -noout/` operator: